# How to show data through XMLHttpRequest() in Angular without using HttpClientModule?

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

[Link to a demo of my Angular app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here I connected a [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) (without using `HttpClientModule`) with my Angular app. When it renders the data is coming in browser console (using `console.log()` method), but I am not able to show this data in the HTML page. I tried using property by this method, but it is not coming.

Can anybody explain me how can I connect other API without using `HttpClientModule` in an Angular app?

Comment: Angular really is a platform these days — I would question why you aren’t using HttpClientModule in this case?

Comment: I am new in angular. I am just learning how angular is structured and how the parts of angular work. I want to learn Angular in depth. If is there any tutorial or book to learn how Component and constructor work (in depth) just let me know.

Comment: What I use is the official docs on angular.io, they go pretty in-depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first declare and assign the data to get the result into view. Say declare in component :-

```
 data: any;
```

You need to parse the xml response result to Json and assign it.

```
data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

And for posting the json in UI use pipe json as :-

```
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

Have updated the bliz  :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-bhnusk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: yes, great... Inside the onreadystatechange function why didn't you use 'this' directly. Can we do like this also -

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         console.log(this.responseText);
         this.data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      }
    };
Here I used 'this.data' in place of 'self.data'.... Could you please explain it

Comment: inside the xhr.onreadystatechange "this" refers to the xhr reference . So i made a let self = this outside the xhr statements to get the components 'this' reference